# No se suman los valores en un campo Total

Tags: javascript, laravel

Al agregar artículos con su correspondientes cantidades, no se suman en el TOTAL, solo se muestra la cantidad del primer articulo agregado.
Dejo aquí una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí parte del js utilizado donde aparecen los datos correspondientes al total:

```
@push ('scripts')
<script>

  var cont=0;
  total=0;
  $("#guardar").hide();

    if (cantidad!="" && cantidad>0)
    {
        if (parseInt(stock)>=parseInt(cantidad))
        {

        total=cantidad;


  function totales()
  {
        $("#ptotal").html("Comp/Amp:  " + total);
        $("#total").val(total);
    }


   function eliminar(index){
    total=total[index];   
    $("#fila" + index).remove();
    evaluar();

  }
</script>
@endpush
```

Agradezco sus respuestas

Comment: esta linea parace que no estas acumulando total=cantidad;
deberia ser total=total+cantidad

Comment: Le agregue ese cambio pero no los suma, me los muestra juntos es decir, Total: Comp/Amp: 0200200

Comment: Parsea la cantidad cuando la sumes al total  ya que parece que esta sumando strings

Comment: Ahora si se suman, pero cuando agrego una linea de articulo con cantidad 200 y la elimino en el total me dice 198. Asi esta la funcion eliminar; function eliminar(index){ total=total-cantidad[index];
    totales()   
    $("#fila" + index).remove();
    evaluar();
  }

Comment: Podrias revisar si estas accediendo de forma correcta a la cantidad que estas elminando porque mas pareciera que estas restando posiciones no cantidades , de igual forma revisa siempre los parseos

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución (sin tener acceso a tus etiquetas HTML):

```
    const cantidad = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.cantidad'))
    let cantidadTotal = 0

    if (cantidad) {
        cantidad.forEach(element => {
            cantidadTotal -= -element.innerText
        })
    }

    console.log(cantidadTotal)
```